# VSCode running different program?

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I have a program that uploads videos to via the vimeo api. But everytime I click run, the program that runs is not the current one, its an old program, which I have now deleted and even deleted from recycle bin, yet everytime I run my vimeo code it runs a completely different program that shouldnt even exist its driving me crazy!

I've tried to adjust my setting file which currently looks like below.

```
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "internalConsole"


        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: maybe it uses file from different place that you expect. Try to create script with different name and run it to see if it will start. You can also check if you can use full path in `"program": "${file}",` . Maybe it starts in different folder then you expect and there is old script.

Comment: you could also check if you have file .pyc or .pyo or subfolder `__pycache__` which can keep version converted bytes code and python may use it to start script faster.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have a script cached somewhere. To troubleshoot please do the following:

- Restart VScode
- Restart PC (if on windows 10 use `shutdown/r /f /t 000` in cmd to force a full restart and avoid windows fast-boot saving anything.)
- check what happens if you run the script manually via `python your script` and see what happens.

Comment if this doesn't help and add more info such as your OS and how you are running your script.

Comment: I have tried restarting VSCode, restarting and shutting down my machine, resarting my machine using the CMD method above and no luck, same issue, also when I run my python script in shell or terminal it still runs the other python script. I have no idea whats happening as I've used this script countless times without issue, now it just runs a different python script!! Driving me crazy.

Comment: I've managed to crack it, but dont quite understand how. I noticed the program it was running was called test.py, so I deleted that and now my vimeo script is running correctly. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: what was your old script's name? and what was your new script's name? just trying to understand for myself what the problem turned out to be.

Answer (score 0):

If you are importing any module like "import some_module" you could change it to "from some_module import *", or the specific function you want.